# JS not working without prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prototypejs

We have this piece of code:

```
<a class="loadbutton" onClick="$('checkout_form').submit(); $(this).update('<img src=\'images/loader/longLoad.gif\' /> Processing'); return false;">Pay now<br /><span class="vsmall">click once</span></a>
```

Which seems to not work if I take out the prototype.js library:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6/prototype.js">
```

But when I use this library, it conflicts with some other code we are using.. so we want to do it without this prototype library, but still have the same effect on the button.

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Am I right in assuming you're using jquery instead of prototype? If so, then here is how it may look:

```
<a class="loadbutton" onClick="$('#checkout_form').submit(); $(this).html('<img src=\'images/loader/longLoad.gif\' /> Processing'); return false;">Pay now<br /><span class="vsmall">click once</span></a>
```

As Ernest mentioned, jQuery.noConflict() may be your best option if you'd like to use both libraries. To do so, you must apply the $.noConflict() before including prototype.

Comment: Hi there, this worked great but the form submit bit doesn't work any more. I would prefer not to use prototype if I can do without using it.

Comment: oops, edited the answer to reflect a jquery selector. $('#some_id') instead of prototypes $('some_id'). should work now

Answer (score 1):

That "$" function is being provided by the prototype library, so that's why it doesn't work when prototype is removed. Is jQuery the other library? jQuery provides a mechanism so that it won't interfere with other libraries that want to use "$".

Comment: Hi there, yes I am using jQuery for other things on the page, would my best bet be using noConflict? Thanks for the answers guys.

Comment: @Kyle: your two choices would be to recode the prototype stuff in jQuery (which wouldn't be too hard) or use noConflict and then change the "$()" used by the jQuery code to "$jQuery()." Which makes more sense depends on the relative amounts of code for both libraries, I suppose.